# C# GridView keep raising unexpected error when paging

Tags: c#, mysql, gridview, paging

I have problem with my gridview, where everything has no problem in the beginning of paging, let say you have a gridview with 3 pages, first page load, second page load, then third page load, then back to second, all no problem, but it seems unstable sometimes that it cant do paging and trigger my try catch error and my system has a security to logout the user. My problem is, whenever this problem arise, the MySQL connection will cut and lost too! And when connect back using any GUI MySQL, it shows error like "Cant connect to MySQL localhost (10048)"

Any experts could help this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, there's nothing wrong with your app. But you are having environment problems, specifically with your connection with MySQL.

Check if your MySQL instance is running OK. Since you mentioned localhost, let's not raise the network issues yet.

Have tried Googling the error message and code?

Comment: By the way my MySQL for that query table is MyISAM, and some is INNODB, do you think this might cause that conflict?